# Ошибка "Не удается продолжить выполнение кода, поскольку система не обнаружила opencv_world480d.dll" visual studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cv2

При попытке запуска кода с использованием opencv2 (предварительно установленном) возникает ошибка: "Не удается продолжить выполнение кода, поскольку система не обнаружила opencv_world480d.dll. Для устранения этой проблемы попробуйте переустановить программу."

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Надо добавить путь к папке, где лежит эта dll в переменную окружения PATH